# bootstrap datepicker needs to allow a past date but maintain a min date

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

Here's my scenario. The datepicker has a minDate of today. This part works
FutureDateField > September 6th 2017

If in a couple days later the user needs to change something in the form the passed date is now blank because it later than today.

Is there anyway to maintain the old date but if the user wanted to change it the datepicker would then use [today] as the min date. Any direction would be appreciated

Comment: can you make a codepen, i'll help you with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up allowing past dates and checkign to make sure the user could only select a past date or the date that was already selected with a custom validator